# Display number of items on listview from another web page asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have two web pages, and I want to display the number of rows the listview has on another page. how can i achieve this? I'm using asp.net by the way

Comment: Did you try anything? Show your work also..

Comment: @Jb Meris my answer updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Session.

First page:

```
Session["num"] = ListView1.Items.Count ;
```

in second page:

```
int count = (int) Session["num"] ;
```

Comment: @Jb Meris my answer updated

Answer (score -1):

You can Use Session to achieve this concept. Session is used for passing values from one page to another page.

In the first page:

Session["count"]=listview.items.count;

In Second Page:

int count=Convert.ToInt32(Session["count"])